# How do I import the QColorConstants namespace in PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5, python-import

I fear the answer will be: You can't, but I'm not sure and I don't see a reason for.

Qt [QColorConstants namespace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolorconstants.html).

From the page url I guess this should work:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColorConstants
```

but it results in:

> cannot import name 'QColorConstants' from 'PyQt5.QtGui'

Comment: What version of PyQt do you have?

Comment: With PyQt5 5.15.4 it works

Comment: As the QColorConstants documentation shows in the very beginning of the page, "This namespace was introduced in Qt 5.14"

Comment: @musicamante: Thanks, this is indeed the problem, I've 5.12.9, though I updated my conda configuration yesterday!